# Leaflet Realtime GeoJSON dynamic marker color change

Tags: javascript, real-time, leaflet, geojson

I have a map built with Leaflet which displays markers from a GeoJSON using [Leaflet-Realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) plugin and [Leaflet-awesome-numbered-marker](https://github.com/Zahidul-Islam/Leaflet.awesome-numbered-marker) plugin. However I noticed that the markers color doesn't change dynamically, but it changes if I reload the page. Here's the code so far:

```
var map = L.map('map', {center: [46.7634, 23.5996], zoom: 14}),
realtime = L.realtime({
    url: 'get_markers.php',
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    interval: 500,

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        'icon': new L.AwesomeNumberMarkers({
                  number: feature.properties.mynumber, 
                  markerColor: feature.properties.status.toLowerCase()
              })

    });
}
}).addTo(map);
```

In `feature.properties.status` is the color code for my markers. I want to change the color of the marker in realtime according to the property in json. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a sample of your GeoJSON?

Comment: Sure, here it is:  

'{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.588973,46.772968]},"properties":{"id":198,"mynumber":"195","status":"RED"}}]}'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `updateFeature` option of `L.Realtime`. It takes a method with three parameters: `feature`, `oldLayer` and `newLayer`. In there just take the `newLayer` and use the `setIcon` method of the marker:

```
updateFeature: function (feature, oldLayer, newLayer) {
    newLayer.setIcon(new L.AwesomeNumberMarkers({
        number: feature.properties.mynumber, 
        markerColor: feature.properties.status.toLowerCase()
    }));
}
```

Unable to test, but that should work.

Reference: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime#-options

Comment: You're right, it works, but I had to declare a function for this, here is the code:    
`realtime.on('update', function(e) {
         updateFeatureIcon = function (fId) {
  var feature = e.features[fId],
         mynumber = feature.properties.mynumber;
         status = feature.properties.status;
            realtime.getLayer(fId).setIcon(new L.AwesomeNumberMarkers({
        number: mynumber, 
        markerColor: status.toLowerCase()
    }));
        };
        
 Object.keys(e.update).forEach(updateFeatureIcon);
});`